# custom button selector

Tags: android, button

Im trying to create custom button and i cant see my problem.

i create in res/drawable/ custom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<item android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/forwardpress"></item>
<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@drawable/forwardhover"></item>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/forward"></item>

</selector>
```

and on main.xml i have this button

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/bFor"
         android:background="@drawable/custom"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right" />
```

The problem is, button is stay presed without animation, (yes i have 3 diferent picture in drawable folder)

Answer (score 0):

Clean and build your project again.

Answer (score 0):

Funny thing is, I for one button works but the other does not

i try this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/backpress" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/back"/>
```

its work but for second button i try the same process

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:drawable="@drawable/forwardpress" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/forward"/>

</selector>
```

for second button doesnt work, wierd...

Comment: clean and build your project again